# How do you add a new key to a dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2, nsdictionary

How do you add a new key to a `Dictionary` in Swift? I'm getting an error :

> This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key address...

Here's my code:

```
let user = [
     "id": id,
     "name" : name
]

if customer.address != nil {
    let address = [
         "street": customer.address.street,
         "zip": customer.address.zip,
    ]

    user.setValue(address, forKey: "address")
}
```

UPDATED Code:

```
var user = [
            "id": customer.id,
            "name" : customer.fullName!,
            "position" : customer.position != nil ? customer.position! : ""
        ]

        if customer.address != nil {
            let address = [
                "street": customer.address!.street,
                "zip":   customer.address!.zip
            ]

            user["address"] = address
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I can not use SetValue for Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313847/why-i-can-not-use-setvalue-for-dictionary)

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary in the first place? You should be creating data models for data like this. It is much better (and easier ... and safer) to have a struct for your data that has properties that you can set. Swift is not JavaScript. Stop treating it like it is.

Comment: @Fogmeister I do have data models, but this is just before I'm send out a request to my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to add different type values in dictionary. if you want to add different type of values use `Any`.
`Any` can represent an instance of any type at all.

for example:

```
var user: [String: Any] = [
  "id": "dd",
  "name" : "ddd"
]

let address = ["street": "ss","zip": "124115"]

user["address"] = address
```

Comment: Yes, that was it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change you user `Dictionary` decalration to `var` instead of constant and then use `subscript` to add new value with key.

```
var user: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "id": id,
    "name" : name
]
user["address"] = address
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "cannot assign through subscript:  subscript is get only"

Comment: @Prabhu be sure that the `user` dictionary is declared as `var` (as Nirav D wrote) and not `let`

Comment: Yes, I changed it to var.

Comment: @Prabhu Is it working now after changing it to `var`?